# 500 Internal Server Error just on Google Chrome when logging into PayPal

Tags: google-chrome, paypal

Whenever I try to visit log in to PayPal on Google Chrome (my current version is 35.0.1916.114 which is the most up to date at the time of writing this), I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Here's the exact one:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@paypal.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

I'm able to visit the homepage fine and I can log in on all other browsers but this has been an issue for some time now (I just haven't gotten around to looking into it). At the moment, I open Firefox just to use PayPal but I used Chrome for everything else so I'm trying to solve it.

Any ideas on why this would be happening? I've seen other questions on the web similar but they are mainly due to people 'buying' through PayPal which isn't a problem for me. I can purchase items on the 'purchase' screens that you get redirected to from a site.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Same in Firefox, this might help as well https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1062042

Comment: I have the same problem. Firefox doesnt works alongside the chrome. Pc restart helps in 100℅ , router dir 300 restart helps in 50℅

Comment: in my case I was using a chome extention that displays headers in a console, while on firefox I didn not have such an extention/add-on. Chrome was dying with 500 headers too big, but firefox wasn't, since it simply ignored those headers

Answer (score 5):

I see this from time to time on a couple of very specific web sites (e.g., Slashdot). All other sites works fine when this happens (and the site works fine in other browsers, including Web Kit based ones). The embarrassingly simple solution is to restart the browser (I try to avoid it since I often have 50+ tabs open). If guess the problem might be session cookies (that would explain why a restart works). As a consequence of this guess, clearing all permanent cookies for PayPal and related sites might be worth considering.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I do like this at the 500 error page

- Click on the **Secure** to the left side of the address bar
- Select **Site settings**
- Select **Reset site settings** at the bottom of the page

Reload the page

Answer (score 0):

in some cases but not all. There appears to be a corrupt session via the cookie or data stored for a specific browser in the java files. Try the following;
1. Download CCleaner (close chrome)
   Remove and clean registry files
   Remove tmp and cached for CHROME as well as cookies
   Clear index.dat file
4. Control Panel / Java-open / clear internet java cached files
5. Make sure you're not using a proxy IP for the web
6. Restart computer
7. Try again

Answer (score -1):

Now that Google separated cookies from permissions I had to delete my cookies separately to get it to work.

- Click on the Secure to the left side of the address bar
- Select Cookies
- Select the wordpress cookies and Remove each one
- Reload page